# How to define a temporal system of Boolean variables?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm sure I could have worded the question better.

There are Boolean Variables connected to certain conditions:

- `Boolean1` = close > Something
- `Boolean2` = close < SomethingElse
- `Boolean3` = SomethingElse > Something

The goal:

- Investigate `Boolean2` only **after** `Boolean1` **was** true.
- Investigate `Boolean3` only **after** `Boolean2` **was** true.
- IF `Boolean3` becomes true then it resets everything, so it makes `Boolean1`, `Boolean2`, even `Boolean3` false. (And everything starts over.)

To approach it with a story:

- The price reaches/exceeds something.
- Only after this happens, we watch if the price reaches/exceeds something else. We are glad then.
- After this step, something else happens so we know we can start over the process. (This is that "reset".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume it happens through multiple bars. The simplest way for this:

```
var bool1 = false
var bool2 = false
var bool3 = false

if close > Something
    bool1 := true

if bool1 and close < SomethingElse
    bool2 := true

if bool2 and SomethingElse > Something
    bool1 := false
    bool2 := false
    // do your bool3 logic
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do it, but I do it like this:

```
condition    = 0
condition   := condition[1] == 0 and Boolean1   ? 1 :
               condition[1] == 1 and Boolean2   ? 2 :
               condition[1] == 2 and Boolean3   ? 0 : nz(condition[1])
Condition1   = condition[1] == 0 and condition == 1
Condition2   = condition[1] == 1 and condition == 2
Condition3   = condition[1] == 2 and condition == 0
```

Comment: :) This is a little different approach, I over-simplified my example code. I'm afraid I can't translate your code into my case. I refined my example code. Would you please fit your answer to it? Thank you!